# Materialize CSS - Mobile devices

Tags: css, materialize

I'm making a site with Materialize from Google but I have some problems with the grid on mobile devices and tablets. I want, for example, to have 1 row and 3 colums on a large screen and 3 colums of 1 row on mobile devices. I follow their instructions but it doesn't works... Somebody can help me ?

Comment: Show us what you've got so far.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col l4 s12">
        <!-- COL #1 -->
    </div>
    <div class="col l4 s12">
        <!-- COL #2 -->
    </div>
    <div class="col l4 s12">
        <!-- COL #3 -->
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what you need. Give the classes `col l4 s12` for each columns inside a row to achieve what you are looking for.

Check the Topic, Creating Responsive Layouts in this [Link](http://materializecss.com/grid.html)